# Change LaTeX equation font size within `eqnarray` in RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I have a **latex** equation as part of an **RMarkdown** document that I'm knitting to an HTML file using **knitr**. I would like to use the LaTeX `eqnarray` to align the equality signs. However, I would also like to change font sizes from the first equation to the next.

This works, but equality signs are not lined up:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Eric"
date: "5/14/2020"
output: html_document
---

\[
\large a = b \times (c + d)\\
{\small\begin{eqnarray}
a &=& \mathrm{var ~a}\\
b &=& \mathrm{var ~b}\\
c &=& \mathrm{var ~c}
\end{eqnarray}}
\]
```

The result:

[image: This works]
I tried many different arrangements of brackets and terms. Here is an example that does not work:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Eric"
date: "5/14/2020"
output: html_document
---

#### Try to line up equal signs AND change font sizes (doesn't work)

\[
\begin{eqnarray}
\large a &=& b \times (c + d)\\
{\small
a &=& \mathrm{var ~a}\\
b &=& \mathrm{var ~b}\\
c &=& \mathrm{var ~c}}
\end{eqnarray}
\]

#### Try again (doesn't work):
\[
\begin{eqnarray}
{\large a &=& b \times (c + d)}
{\small
\\a &=& \mathrm{var ~a}\\
b &=& \mathrm{var ~b}\\
c &=& \mathrm{var ~c}}
\end{eqnarray}
\]
```

**How do I line up the equal signs using `eqnarray` while changing font sizes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you'd want:

```
\[
\small
\begin{eqnarray}
{\large a}\ & {\large =} & {\large b \times (c + d)}\\
a &=& \mathrm{var ~a}\\
b &=& \mathrm{var ~b}\\
c &=& \mathrm{var ~c}
\end{eqnarray}
\]
```

The spacing for the `a` is a little bit off, which is why I added the `\` after it.  You might want to fiddle with that.